# Expression evaluation in C/C++ doesnt follow BODMAS rule?

Tags: c++, c

When a expression is evaluated in C/C++, does it follow BODMAS [Bracket open Division Multiply Addition Substraction] rule? If not then how they are evaluated?

EDIT: More clearly, If the following expression is evaluated  according to BODMAS rule,

(5 + 3)/8*9

First what is in brackets is processed.

8/8*9.

Then Division is done.

1*9

And then multiplication and so on.

Comment: I thought it was BEDMAS for Brackets **Exponents** Division Multiplication Addition Subtraction?

Comment: (Powers, Parentheses), Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction is what my 6th grade teacher taught me. (Thanks Dr. Fegley!)

Comment: I learned BODMAS where the O was "of", as in "1/2 of 8" (pretty sure I learned that well before exponents were introduced). I always thought the addition of a fake "of" operator was a poor excuse to get a pronounceable acronym.

Comment: I've always heard `PEMDAS` - Parentheses, Exponentiation, Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction.

Comment: Your title states that C++ doesn’t follow BODMAS. What makes you think that? Have you found an expression that behaves weirdly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are far more operators than that. You can find a precedence tables for [C++](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence) and [C](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

But yes, you'll find it respects that. (Though I'm not sure it's exactly what you've said...)

Comment: That's how they're _parsed_. Evaluation is not guaranteed to happen in that order.

Comment: @MSalters: Sub-expressions have unspecified evaluation order, yes.

Answer (score 6):

There are two answers to this question.

One is that C++ *does* follow standard mathematical precedence rules, which you refer to as BODMAS. You can see the order in which C++ associates all its operators [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence).

However, if any of the expressions involved in the operation have side effects, then C++ is *not* guaranteed to evaluate them in what one might consider to be standard mathematical order. That's sort of an advanced topic, however.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have given you links to operator precedence lists. These are well and good. However, if you need to look at an operator precedence table to determine what your code tells computers to do, *please* take pity on your code's maintainers (including future you) and just use parentheses. It makes your intention much clearer and saves time and heartache in the long run.

Comment: A good rule to follow. My code always has more parentheses than necessary, but my code always works.

Comment: I on the other hand think that many adjacent parentheses make code *much* harder to read and thus I always strive to reduce the number of parentheses if readability doesn’t suffer (which is apparently a subjective measure).

Comment: In general, if it's multiplication vs. addition, I'll leave them out but for stuff like pointer dereferencing and boolean vs. bitwise operators, I find it safer to keep them around (`if (foo & bar != 0)`)

Comment: I deliberately don't memorize the precedence table.  That way, if it's likely to be unclear to somebody else, then it's likely to be unclear to me and I'll instinctively put parentheses around it.

Answer (score 1):

C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k.aspx

C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

C applies the operators in arithmetic expressions in a precise sequence determined by the following rules of operator precedence, which are generally the same as those in algebra:

Operators in expressions contained within pairs of parentheses are evaluated first. Parentheses are said to be at the “highest level of precedence.” In cases of nested, or embedded, parentheses, such as
    ( ( a + b ) + c )
the operators in the innermost pair of parentheses are applied first.

Multiplication, division and remainder operations are applied next. If an expression contains several multiplication, division and remainder operations, evaluation proceeds from left to right. Multiplication, division and remainder are said to be on the same level of precedence.
Addition and subtraction operations are evaluated next. If an expression contains several addition and subtraction operations, evaluation proceeds from left to right. Addition and subtraction also have the same level of precedence, which is lower than the precedence of the multiplication, division and remainder operations.
The assignment operator (=) is evaluated last.

Answer (score -2):

I found an expression that doesn’t follow “BODMAS”. Here is my c program for your reference

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int a = 6;
  int b = 4;
  int c = 2;
  int result;
  result = a - b + c; // 4
  printf("%d \n", result);

  result = a + b / c; // 8
  printf("%d \n", result);

  result = (a + b) / c; // 5
  printf("%d \n", result);

  return 0;
}
```