# Multiplication vs Division in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence

Does C follow [BODMAS rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics)? I am confused with multiplication and division.

Does multiplication has higher precedence over division or it is other way round?

Comment: [Yes, and then some](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `*`, `/`, `%` are of equal precedence.  Evaluate left to right

Comment: What about BODMAS rule?

Comment: What about it? BODMAS doesn't imply that division has a different precedence than multiplication (yes, I am aware of all of these facebook holywars and it is pissing me off).

Comment: @StoryTeller "Yes" is a wrong answer (to the second question)..

Comment: @AkShayMahajan This link might help you. Its more about C++  and you can find an answer for C too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017954/expression-evaluation-in-c-c-doesnt-follow-bodmas-rule

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good thing I answered the first then.

Answer (score 5):

Multiplication, division, and remainder have the same precedence, and associate left-to-right.

For example, `x * y / z` is the same as `(x * y) / z` and
`x / y * z` is the same as `(x / y) * z`.

Whether this matches the BODMAS rule seems to be a matter of some controversy, but that's a question about the meaning of BODMAS, not about the semantics of C. The linked [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics) says that "multiplication and division are of equal precedence", which is consistent with C (except that it doesn't mention C's remainder operator **`%`**).

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to the N1570 draft of C11) doesn't directly define "operator precedence". Instead, it defines the hierarchical syntax of expressions. For example, the syntax for a *multiplicative-expression* (defined in section 6.5.5) is:

> *multiplicative-expression*:
>        *cast-expression*
>        *multiplicative-expression* **`*`** *cast-expression*
>        *multiplicative-expression* **`/`** *cast-expression*
>        *multiplicative-expression* **`%`** *cast-expression*

A *cast-expression* (6.5.4) may or may not include a cast operator; it's any expression that can appear as a term in a *multiplicative-expression*.

Comment: Note: `%` is better called the _remainder_ operator as _modulus_, which has various math definitions concerning negative operands, is not defined in C.  Informative answer about BODMAS.